# How to construct this Laurent series?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, power-series

How do I construct the following Laurent series (clipped off Wolfram Alpha)?

I know that the numerator can be written as $-1+\frac{\pi}2 z-...$

Alternatively (without the Laurent series), how can I see that the pole at $1$ is of order $2$?

[image]

Comment: To investigate the singularity at $z=1$, determine that the order of the zero in the denominator is $4$ and the order of the zero in the numerator is ..., then compare these two.

Comment: Order 1 is incorrect.

Comment: @GEdgar Oh sorry, I made a mistake, you're right of course. But why does [denom's zero's order]-[numerator's zero's order] give the function's pole's order? Is this a theorem, or is it merely a good guess for further verification (using say DonAntonio's suggestion below)? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is a theorem.  It's great for poles.  When there are essential singularities in both numerator and denominator, this will not help, though.

Comment: @GEdgar Why does having essential singularities in both num and denom invalidate this theorem?

Comment: Because "order of zero" or "order of pole" is undefined at an essential singularity.  So we cannot subtract to get information about the singularity of the quotient.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks. Btw, do the order of a zero and the multiplicity of a zero refer to exactly the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By l'Hospital, check that

$$\lim_{z\to 1}f(z)\,$$

isn't finite, so you have a pole. Now check that also

$$\lim_{z\to 1}(z-1)f(z)\,$$

isn't finite, but

$$\lim_{z\to 1}(z-1)^2f(z)\,$$

*is finite* , so the pole has order two.

**Added on request:** Let us write:

$$\sin\frac{\pi}{2}z=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(z-1)+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\cos\frac{\pi}{2}(z-1)=1-\frac{\pi^2}{8}(z-1)^2+\frac{\pi^4}{24\cdot 16}(z-1)^4-\ldots$$

$$\frac{1}{z^5}=\frac{1}{(1+(z-1))^5}=\left(1-(z-1)+(z-1)^2-(z-1)^3+\ldots\right)^5=1-5(z-1)+\ldots$$

The first expansion above is true for any $\,z\,$, the second though only for $\,|z-1|<1\,$ , which we can assume for $\,z\,$ pretty close to $\,1\,$ , thus

$$\frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{2}z-1}{z^5(z-1)^4}=\frac{1}{(z-1)^4}\left(-\frac{\pi^2}{8}(z-1)^2-\ldots\right)\left(1-5(z-1)+\ldots\right)=$$

$$=\frac{1}{(z-1)^4}\left(-\frac{\pi^2}{8}(z-1)^2+\frac{5\pi^2}{8}(z-1)^3+\ldots\right)=-\frac{\pi^2}{8(z-1)^2}+\frac{5\pi^2}{8(z-1)}+\ldots$$

The advantage in the above is that you see $\,z=1\,$ is a double pole **and** also you can see the residue!

Comment: Hey thank you! I like this definitive answer, but differentiating the numerator and denom multiple times (l'Hopital's) did get a bit tedious and hardgoing.

Comment: Yes, I know but since you asked "alternatively, *without Laurent Series*", well...

Comment: Oh, you mean it's easier to construct a Laurent series for this problem? Pray tell how! I understand Mhenni's working, but I don't know what to do from there; also it seems clever and I prefer a more general(enlightening) technique if possible.

Comment: See the stuff I just added to my answer. When one's interested only in the residule or a pole's multiplicity, it is usually easy to "cut off" the several expansions at a reasonable small power and thus just focus in what we're interested.

Comment: Thank you, Don, for enlightening me! Yes, I see why the Laurent series is the best. Btw you missed squaring the $\pi$s in the last lot of equations.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Already corrected.

Answer (score 3):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357501/determining-laurent-series/357509#357509).

**Hint:** Here is a start
$$ \frac{\sin\left(\frac{(z-1)\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-1}{(z-1)^4}(1+(z-1))^{-5}=\frac{\cos\left(\frac{(z-1)\pi}{2}\right)-1}{(z-1)^4}(1+(z-1))^{-5} .$$

Now, just expand the series and collect terms of powers of $z-1$.

Comment: @Ryan: You are welcome.