# Classify the singularity - $\frac{1}{e^z-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, singularity

**Definition :** A isolated singularity is a *pole* of ordre $m$ if $f(z)= \sum_{k=-m}^{\infty} a_k (z-z_0)^k$, $a_m \not= 0$

I have to classify the singularity (removable, pole and essential) of $\frac{1}{e^z-1}$. I know that $e^z-1=0 \iff e^z=1 \iff z = 2\pi k i = z_k$ for each $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. In using what I found, the solution of the book explain that as the derivative of $e^z$ doesn't vanish at $z_k$, so each $z_k$ are a simple pole, but it is not clear at all **how the definition is used (??)**.
Someone explain that $\lim_{z\to i2n\pi}\frac{z-i2n\pi}{e^z-e^{i2n\pi}}=\left. \frac{1}{\frac {de^z}{dz}}\right|_{z=i2n\pi}=1$, but how is it related to the definition?

Is anyone could explain to me the solution of the book? **(Please explain in details)** It is maybe a silly question, but I am only 13 years old, and sometime I need help to unblock on a subject.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407499/type-of-singularities-of-fraczez-1?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some preliminaries: If $f$ is a complex function with $f(z_0) = 0$, then $f$ has a **simple zero** at $z_0$ if there exists a holomorphic function $g$ within a neighbourhood of $z_0$ such that $g(z_0) \neq 0$, and $f(z) = (z-z_0)g(z)$.

If $f$ has a simple zero at $z_0$, then $1/f$ has a **simple pole** at $z_0$.

Expanding the series for $e^z - 1$, we find
$$ e^z - 1 = -1 + \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{z^j}{j!} = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{z^j}{j!}
$$
Hence $e^z - 1$ has a simple zero at $0$, and simple zeroes at $2\pi i k$ by the periodicity of $e^z$. To see this, you can divide the series by $z$.

Hence $\frac{1}{e^z - 1}$ has a simple pole at $2\pi i k$.

Comment: @george That shows the order of the zero of $e^z$ at $2\pi i n$ is the same as $z - 2\pi i n$, and so does their difference. Hence the difference's reciprocal has a simple pole.

Comment: @george The point is to show the order of the zeroes of $e^z - 1$.

Comment: @george If $\lim_{z \to z_0} f(z)/g(z) = 1$ while $f(z_0) = 0 = g(z_0)$, the orders of their zeroes are the same. By the definition of zero, $f - g$ has the zero of same order at $z_0$.

Comment: Now I understand. There exists many equivalent definitions for the same notion; for example : the order of a zero, the pole of an isolated singularity, etc.