# Why is $0$ a pole of first order of $\frac{1}{e^z-1}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am working on the following exercise:

> Classify the isolated singularity $0$ of $\frac{1}{e^z-1}$.

I know that $0$ is a pole of first order, but I am struggling to prove it. My attempt goes as follows:

Using the power series-definition of $e^x$ it is easy to see that:

$$\frac{1}{e^z-1} = \frac{1}{z} \cdot \biggl(1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{(n+1)!} \biggr)^{-1}$$

According to my definition for $0$ to be a pole of first order it has to be a removable singularity of the function $$z\cdot \frac{1}{z} \biggl(1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{(n+1)!} \biggr)^{-1} = \biggl(1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{(n+1)!} \biggr)^{-1}.$$

But I do not see why $0$ should be removable in $\biggl(1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{(n+1)!} \biggr)^{-1}$. Could you help me?

Comment: Plug in $z=0$ and you get $(1)^{-1}=1$ but you have assumed that $z\cdot\frac1z=1$ i.e. the singularity is removable.

Comment: Plugging in $z=0$ into the last expression results in no problems. That's why it is a removable singularity, that expression is the analytic function you can replace the original with to be continuous at $z=0$

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1725325/classify-the-singularity-frac1ez-1) (+ linked therein)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

$$
g(z) = e^z-1
$$

You can simply notice two things:

1. $g(0)=0$. This is trivial to assert that it is indeed a pole.
2. The limit: 
   $$
   \lim_{z\to0}\frac{g(z)}{z} = 1
   $$

Is finite and non-zero, hence 1 is the multiplicity of the root of $g$ (hence the multiplicity of your pole). You can compute the limit with L'Hospital's rule.