# Find the Laurent series at the given point and its residue

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

> a) $\displaystyle \frac{\sin(z)}{(z-\pi)^2}$ at $z_0=\pi$
>
> b) $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1-\cos(z)}$ at $z_0=0$

I'm having trouble understanding Laurent series, please help!

Comment: [related problem 1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345139/how-to-construct-this-laurent-series/345160#345160), [related problem 2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357501/determining-laurent-series/357509#357509).

Answer (score 1):

For example

$$\frac{\sin z}{(z-\pi)^2}=\frac{1}{(z-\pi)^2}\sin(z-\pi+\pi)=-\frac{1}{(z-\pi)^2}\sin(z-\pi)=$$

$$=-\frac{1}{(z-\pi)^2}\left((z-\pi)-\frac{(z-\pi)^3}{3!}+\ldots\right)=-\frac{1}{z-\pi}+\frac{z-\pi}{6}-\ldots$$

Comment: ahh thanks so the residue would be -1 right?

Comment: Yes, indeed so .

Answer (score 1):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357501/determining-laurent-series/357509#357509). For the second one, you can advance as
$$ \frac{1}{1-\cos(z)} = \frac{1}{\frac{z^2}{2!}-\frac{z^4}{2!}+\frac{z^6}{6!}-\ldots }= \frac{1}{\frac{z^2}{2!} \left(1-\frac{2! z^2}{4!}+\frac{2! z^4}{6!}-\ldots \right) } $$

$$ =\frac{2}{z^2} \left(1-\left(\frac{2! z^2}{4!}-\frac{2! z^4}{6!}+\ldots\right)  \right)^{-1} =\frac{2}{z^2}( 1-t )^{-1}, $$

where $t=\left(\frac{2! z^2}{4!}-\frac{2! z^4}{6!}+\ldots\right).$

$$\implies \frac{2}{z^2}( 1-t )^{-1}=\frac{2}{z^2}( 1+t+t^2+t^3+\ldots )$$

$$ =\frac{2}{z^2} \left(1+\left(\frac{2! z^2}{4!}-\frac{2! z^4}{6!}+\ldots\right)+\left(\frac{2! z^2}{4!}-\frac{2! z^4}{6!}+\ldots\right)^2 + \dots \right)  $$

$$ =\frac{2}{z^2} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{z^2}{120}+\ldots\,. $$

Clearly, the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ is $0$. Note that, we have used the identity

$$ (1-x)^{-1}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots\,. $$

**Different approach:** You can use another technique to find the residue without using the Laurent series. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367940/difficulties-performing-laurent-series-expansions-to-determine-residues/367956#367956) for details.

Comment: thanks for the response! I have a question, in the inner parenthesis of the third equality, why are the signs not alternating anymore (as they do in cos(z))?

Comment: @Kelly: I added more material. I hope it is clear now.